# Connect mongodb to ec2

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04

I followed https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/18/react-nodejs-on-aws-how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-amazon-ec2 and was able to configure nginx to server my static react file. Ive also managed to get the following message when starting pm2 for server.js which for all intents and purposes seems like it the right thing.

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/home/ubuntu/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
[PM2] Starting /opt/back-end/server.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
┌─────┬───────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name      │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ server    │ default     │ 1.0.0   │ fork    │ 19411    │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 23.1mb   │ root     │ disabled │
```

Here is my app.listen section of server.js

```
const PORT = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 80 || 4000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

My sites-available config

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name directmailapp.be www.directmailapp.be;

  # react app & front-end files
  location / {
    root /opt/front-end/build;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  # node api reverse proxy
  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
  }
}
~
```

in my client side package.json i am listening to port 4000.

Ive tried to ssh tunnel but since im on putty they dont exactly keep the name of the ppk file so if someone knows the name of what that ppk file becomes in the grep for .pem, maybe that is a missing piece.

I wish there was more info I could provide, and if someone thinks they can help and needs to know more info im happy to look through my things.

Thanks

Comment: why isn't enough to use `express` for the server?

Comment: I am using express. sorry i can post the entire server.js if that might help.

Comment: check this one https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html

Comment: thanks for following up. you know its funny in one guide for sites available that everyone uses he lists it as localhost:4000 i had to go digging for an hour or two to find an example that said its the local private ip of  your amazon instance after that it worked thanks tho

Comment: no worries, i'm also setting up nodejs+mongodb+express so we could keep in touch. be careful cause with errors they can bill you awfully. im on linux though

Comment: this page https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/ has been very heplful to me so far.